# ssh key format node.js

Tags: node.js, ssh, ssh2, node-ssh

I've tried using ssh2 and node-ssh libraries to connect,
but I always get "Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format"
I'm getting the key from AWS secret manager in this format `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- ....---END PRIVATE KEY-----`, I tried adding 'BEGIN RSA' or 'BEGIN OPENSSH' (also added them at the end of the file) still getting the same error, I tried using `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa` and navigate to this file and still I get this error, I managed to workaround with exec a child process but it's not ideal, I'm trying to avoid saving the key as file and use directly the string I'm getting from the secret manager

```
ssh.connect({
  host: 'my-server.example.com',
  port: 22,
  username: 'my-username',
  privateKey: // string from secret manager in the format mentioned above
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can refer below updates using the `node-ssh` npm package
more can be seen here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh/v/13.1.0

```
ssh.connect({
  host: 'localhost',
  username: 'steel',
  privateKeyPath: '/home/steel/.ssh/id_rsa'
})

// or with inline privateKey

ssh.connect({
  host: 'localhost',
  username: 'steel',
  privateKey: Buffer.from('...')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A private key that starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` is an *encrypted* private key. You need to provide an appropriate key passphrase in order to use it.

I'm not familiar with node.js in general (nor node-ssh in particular), but looking at [the documentation for `node-ssh`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh) it looks like there are options for providing the passphrase. The "API" section shows:

```
declare type Config = ConnectConfig & {
    host?: string;
    port?: number;
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
    privateKeyPath?: string;
    privateKey?: string;
    passphrase?: string;
    tryKeyboard?: boolean;
    onKeyboardInteractive?: (
      name: string,
      instructions: string,
      lang: string,
      prompts: Prompt[],
      finish: (responses: string[]) => void
    ) => void;
};
```

So you either need:

```
ssh.connect({
  host: 'my-server.example.com',
  port: 22,
  username: 'my-username',
  privateKey: // string from secret manager in the format mentioned above,
  passphrase: // key passphrase
});
```

Or you need to store an *unencrypted* private key in your secrets manager. An unencrypted private key starts with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`.